# Is there reason for me to believe that Stack Overflow's servers have a lower chance of losing all its data than other servers?

Tags: discussion, technology

Like what happened in Magnolia a few years ago, and what happened with Digg a year ago or so.

What preventative measures are in place? As in, redundant servers and backups of old data?

Comment: You can't. If anything you post is vital to you, I suggest keeping copies of the data dumps.

Comment: Okay thanks. I just changed the content of my post.

Comment: Hurricanes ravage the Eastern seaboard of the US, tornados hit the midwest, wildfires strike everywhere, turrists lurk in the shadows! Pretty much anywhere you put a server, it could go down. Pointing to California as an especially bad place is kinda silly.

Comment: The thing is - with everything else you get prior warning (so you can quickly archive everything). With earthquakes, there's no prior warning at all.

Comment: Also, see http://www.globaldatavault.com/natural-disaster-threat-maps.htm and http://www.quora.com/In-terms-of-natural-disasters-what-would-be-the-safest-place-in-the-world-to-live

Anyways, I'm more concerned with Magnolia/Digg-like incidents than with natural disasters. So server redundancy and backups are more important

Comment: Don't forget Nibiru in 2012! The Mayans predicted it!

Comment: Their maps are suspect at best. Try telling my insurance company that coastal NC has Below Average flood risk...

Comment: Uhh, redundancy? It helps with doomsday scenarios *and* performance. Seems like a win-win. And, no, the datacenter is not in Cali.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data is made available in bimonthly [data dumps](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/) under the [CC-by-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license. There are some sites (at least a dozen I think) that host data from the dumps in different forms, so I think even in a major disaster most of the data could be recovered.  Feel free to host a mirror yourself though as long as you comply with the above license.

Also, the data center [moved to NY](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/datacenter-migration-oct-23/) back in October.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that that's not all the data, just the public info. It includes the post bodies, which is the most important part, but lots of stuff would be missing (e.g. voting information)

Comment: IIRC, chat (and SEDE, too?) are hosted on the older hardware in Oregon. Also, Michael is correct -- the public data dumps do not contain critical internal information: they are not suitable backups, although as a last resort they could be used as *part* of a recovery procedure.